# mysql query to get data ordered by date, time, and name (but don't want to split common names apart under each date)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL query that produces this output ordered like this:

[image: current output]

Instead I'd like the output ordered like this:
[image: desired output]

I'm not sure how to write the query so that it orders the data the way I need it.  I need the data sorted by date DESC, then by time DESC, but also to chunk common 'markers_name' elements together.  (I only want them chunked together for each date).

This is the query I'm using:

```
SELECT markers.name AS markers_name, 
       conditions.time AS conditions_time, 
       conditions.date AS conditions_date, 
       station.name AS station_name 
FROM markers, conditions, users 
WHERE conditions.markers_id = markers.id 
AND (conditions.station_id = station.id)
ORDER BY date DESC, markers.name, time DESC 
LIMIT 100
```

(P.S. I omitted showing the station_name in my output tables, but they do show up in my real query.)

**EDIT:**
I've added some more tables in an attempt to explain the problem better.
Note that "chunk" isn't really returned by the query.  I just added that to help with the conversation.  Each chunk has a common date.

Here is output after I tried ORDER BY date DESC , markers.name DESC , time DESC
[image: Desired output]

And here is my desired output:

[image]

Compare 'Chunk 4' in the two outputs.  The upper table orders by name descending.  This is not desired.  Marker_name 'd' has the newest information so I want it to be first.  'C' has the next newest information.  'f' has the oldest information.  The next table shows the ordering that I need.

Hopefully this conveys the issue better.  Can anyone help?

**EDIT 2**
I tried this proposed answer: "ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC, markers.name DESC" but it didn't work.

[image: order by date, time, name]

Note that chunk 3 is ordered by time.  The 'e' and 'b' rows are not grouped together.

Comment: what happens if you try my suggested query?? what does it return?

Comment: Hi Saher, I edited the original question.  Hopefully it becomes more clear.  I think it's going to be something like ORDER BY (select min(c2.time) from conditions c2 where c2.marker_id = markers.id) DESC, markers_name, time DESC LIMIT 100';  but that's not quite it either....

Comment: I think this happens because you order the name before the time. Switch the order of time and markers.name and I think you get the right result , don't you?

Comment: That doesn't do it either.  When we order by time first the names no longer get grouped together (see EDIT 2).  I think the sort by name would only kick in when the times were the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the list of `MAX(time)` values for every combination of `(markers_id, date)` in `conditions`, then join that list to the rowset you are getting from your present query, and use the `MAX(time)` values for sorting:

```
SELECT
  m.name AS markers_name,
  c.time AS conditions_time,
  c.date AS conditions_date,
  s.name AS station_name
FROM markers m
  INNER JOIN conditions c ON c.markers_id = m.id
  INNER JOIN station s    ON c.station_id = s.id
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      markers_id,
      date,
      MAX(time) AS time
    FROM conditions
    GROUP BY
      markers_id,
      date
  ) mx ON c.markers_id = mx.markers_id AND c.date = mx.date
ORDER BY
  c.date DESC,
  mx.time DESC,
  m.name DESC,
  c.time DESC
```

Comment: This looks complicated enough (to my mediocre skills) to be promissing!  Right now I'm getting this error, but I'm trying to sort it out: #1054 - Unknown column 'conditions_date' in 'group statement'

Comment: You're a bloody genius mate!  This works! just had to change conditions_date to date.  ... i have a lot to learn about mysql...

Comment: I'm so sorry, I forgot to clean that last instance up. Of course, I meant `date` there instead of `conditions_date`. Congrats on figuring out that little mess! :)

Comment: Hi Andriy, I need to extend this query now and I was wondering if you might be able to help.  The conditions table has a 'private' column.  If 'private' is set to 1 only some people are allowed to see the results of the query.  The people that can see it include the person that created the conditions report and that person's contacts.  The conditions table has a 'user_id', which contains the id of the person that created the conditions report.  The contacts are obtained from a 'contacts' table which has two fields: 'user_id' and 'friend_id'.  Any chance you could help?  Thank you very much.

Comment: Should have mentioned that I would have the user_id of the person making the query.

Answer (score 0):

what happens if in your query in the ORDER BY you add `DESC` for markers.name

... `ORDER BY date DESC, markers.name **DESC**, time DESC LIMIT 100`   ?

Comment: @user418775 : what happens if you try my suggested query?? what does it return?

Comment: Thanks, this would happen to order things properly for this one example because 'Location 2' happens to come after 'Location 1' when sorted alphabetically. I'm trying to figure out how to rewrite my question now.

Comment: @user418775 :what happens then if you switch the order: ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC, markers.name DESC ???

Comment: That ends up ordering by time and the names don't get groped together.  I'll attach a screenshot to the question.